# Eclipse plugin's to format XML/XSLT's

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Are there any eclipse plugins to format XML/XSLT's ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an XML editor with syntax help and formatting abilities that's maintained at eclipse.org in the WTP project. The easiest way to get it is to download Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers packages.

Or you can go to the central repository for eclipse.org plugins. For Eclipse 3.6 "Helios", that would be this one: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/

Filter on XML to find the right feature to install.